# JavaScript: Getting the right UI element in a list of them

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I am building a UI in JavaScript that involves adding a column of checkBoxes:

```
for (var key in ProcessAndPortList.list) 
{
    if (ProcessAndPortList.list.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
        var dataRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);
        var dataCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        dataCell.textContent = key;

        dataCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        dataCell.textContent = ProcessAndPortList.list[key].port;

        var terminationCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
        terminationCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
        terminationCheckbox.id = key;
        terminationCheckbox.checked = ProcessAndPortList.list[key].markedForTermination;
        terminationCheckbox.onchange = function() {
            var isChecked = terminationCheckbox.checked;
            markForTermination(key, isChecked);
        };
        var terminateCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        terminateCell.appendChild(terminationCheckbox);
    }
}
```

The problem comes in associating the correct ID to the callback for when the checkbox for each entry is checked. I can't seem to get *that* checkbox's ID to the function. I only ever get the last checkBox's ID. How can I get the correct ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this should work:

```
terminationCheckbox.onchange = function() {
    markForTermination(this.id, this.checked);
};
```

Comment: Coming from a C++ background, I keep forgetting that 'this' is the owner of the function being executed. Using, ahem, this solution works!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you capture the variable key with that closure. But key changes on each iteration of the for loop. Capture some variable that is declared inside the loop instead.

```
for (var key in ProcessAndPortList.list) 
{
    if (ProcessAndPortList.list.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
        var local_scope_key = key
        var dataRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);
        var dataCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        dataCell.textContent = key;

        dataCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        dataCell.textContent = ProcessAndPortList.list[key].port;

        var terminationCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
        terminationCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
        terminationCheckbox.id = key;
        terminationCheckbox.checked = ProcessAndPortList.list[key].markedForTermination;
        terminationCheckbox.onchange = function() {
            var isChecked = terminationCheckbox.checked;
            markForTermination(local_scope_key, isChecked);
        };
        var terminateCell = dataRow.insertCell(-1);
        terminateCell.appendChild(terminationCheckbox);
    }
}
```